# Multiple selection LazyColumn recompose issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I encountered a recomposition issue when implementing a multi selection on Android Jetpack Compose. I have a working solution but some tricky with `@Stable` annotation of class.

Perhaps someone will offer ideas for another implementation.

---

Prerequisites:

1. I have model class from external library (simple java) which is displayed in LazyColumn as item;
2. LazyColumn must be implement multiple selection and save selected item by rememberSaveable function.

For implement selection i wrote selector class with function to get keys, that saved with Bundle:

```kotlin
class Selector<I, K> (
    private val selectable: SnapshotStateList<I>,
    private val keyProvider: (I) -> (K)
)
```

Full code: [**GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/h8leet/5bc4d8cbc7736c9f8401cd365a420118)

Selection states i am store in the map with key and state of selection.

```kotlin
private val _selectedStates = ArrayMap<K, WeakReference<MutableState<Boolean>>>()
val selectedState: (I) -> State<Boolean>
    get() = state@{ item ->
        val key = keyProvider(item)
        val currentState = _selectedStates[key]?.get()
        return@state if (currentState != null) {
            currentState
        } else {
            val state = mutableStateOf(_selection.containsKey(key))
            _selectedStates[key] = WeakReference(state)
            state
        }
    }
```

I am read state in items block of LazyColumn and change background of item dependented from state.

```kotlin
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentPadding = contentPadding,
    state = listState
) {
    items(
        items = items,
        key = { item -> item.hashCode() }
    ) { item ->
        val selectedState = selector.selectedState(item)
        val isSelected = { selectedState.value }
        /* Some code with isSelected() reading */
    }
}
```

So recomposing issue is happening on `contentPadding` changes. On scrolling `TopAppBar` of `Scaffold` the `contentPadding` changes and recompose all items in `LazyColumn` due to `_selectedStates` is not stable property.

**Working solution:**
The my last solution is annotate the `Selector` with `@Stable` and this helps me to avoid unnecessary recomposes but i think it's some tricky.

**Another:**
On changing map to `SnapshotStateMap` (`mutableStateMapOf<>()`) the unnecessary recomposing is happening on first load of item:

1. Selected state is loading;
2. State put in the map that changes `_selectedStates`;
3. Due to changes of state map, state map in `items` of `LazyColumn` is reloaded.

`remember { selector.selectedState }` is not helps.

**And more:**
If selection states is not storing and only provides function `isSelected` recomposing of each item is happening on any selection changes:

```kotlin
val isSelected: (I) -> Boolean = { item -> _selection.contains(keyProvider(item)) }
```

---

Maybe there is another stable solution for saving individual selected states for each item?